# How to convert 450M into 450,000,000 in R

Tags: r

I currently am trying to convert strings that are of the form "450B" (where B stands for billion) into 450,000,000,000. Similarly with strings of the form "200M", i am trying to convert these into numeric form; 200,000,000.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to replace the 'B', 'M' with '1e9', '1e6' using `gsubfn`, loop through the values (`sapply(..`) and use that `eval(parse(` to get the numeric output.  If we need to `format` the output as showed in the OP's post, we can use `formatC`.

```
library(gsubfn)
r1 <- unname(sapply(gsubfn('\\D+', list(B= '*1e9', M= '*1e6'), v1), 
                function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
formatC(r1, format='f', digits=0, big.mark=',')
#[1] "450,000,000,000" "200,000,000"     "220,000,000,000" "20,000,000"
```

---

Or without using any package, we can use `gsub/sub` to replace the numeric and non-numeric part and replace the non-numeric elements by '1e6', '1e9' by matching and multiply with numeric part.

```
r2 <- unname(c(B=1e9, M= 1e6)[gsub('\\d+', '', v1)]* as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', v1)))

formatC(r2, format='f', digits=0, big.mark=',')
#[1] "450,000,000,000" "200,000,000"     "220,000,000,000" "20,000,000"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('450B', '200M', '220B', '20M')
```